# I can't install anything via terminal after installing ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: gnome-terminal, ppa

I just install the new Ubuntu 18.04LTS but after some basic setups I now realize that I can't install anything via terminal or adding PPAs

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update --fix-missing &&  sudo apt upgrade`. Does the Ubuntu Software Center still work?

Comment: It does work. And when I try to install jdk for example, the erro message says  **E:   Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer**